# Turning a df with 3 columns into 6 (special case with NA)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataframe:

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("foo","bar","cake") , col1 = c("1a/1b","1a","1b"), col2 = c("2b","2a","2b"), col3=c("3b","3b/3a",NA))
```

> ```
>    col1 col2  col3
> 1 1a/1b   2b    3b
> 2    1a   2a 3a/3b
> 3    1b   2b  <NA>
> ```

I would like to turn this into 6 columns with names `1a 1b 2a 2b 3a 3c`

Here's what I currently have (I noticed that there are NA values which I would like to keep as NA):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep="/") %>%
  mutate(i1 = 1) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = i1, values_fill = list(i1 = NA))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 8
>   ID     `1a`  `1b`  `2b`  `3b`  `2a`  `3a`  `NA`
>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 foo       1     1     1     1     0     0     0
> 2 bar       1     0     0     1     1     1     0
> 3 cake      0     1     1     0     0     0     1
> ```

**Desired Output**

> ```
> ID        `1a`  `1b`  `2b`  `3b`  `2a`  `3a`
>     <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 foo       1     1     1     1     0     0
> 2 bar       1     0     0     1     1     1
> 3 cake      0     1     1     NA    0     NA
> ```

Comment: Can you explain the logic? How exactly does the NA value get linked to 2a and 3a?

Comment: I made a mistake with 3a. Sorry about that! just fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #Get the data in long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  #Separate into different rows
  separate_rows(value, sep="/") %>%
  #Create a dummy column
  mutate(i1 = 1) %>%
  #Expand the missing combinations for each ID
  complete(ID, value = unique(value)) %>%
  #Get only the number from the value
  mutate(num = readr::parse_number(value)) %>%
  #Group by ID and number
  group_by(ID, num) %>%
  #Change to 0 the values with NA and has atleast one non-NA in the group
  mutate(i1 = replace(i1, is.na(i1) & any(!is.na(i1)), 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #Drop num and name column
  select(-num, -name) %>%
  #Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = i1)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  ID     `1a`  `1b`  `2a`  `2b`  `3a`  `3b`
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 bar       1     0     1     0     1     1
#2 cake      0     1     0     1    NA    NA
#3 foo       1     1     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: I totally forgot that the column names in the real df don't start with numbers (ie Fya/Fyb, "Mutation exists"/"Mutation not found"). Should I post again with updated cells?

Comment: @user171558 you need to change this part of the code `mutate(num = readr::parse_number(value))` to capture common part in the column.